# In VRBox Designing and other VRVideo and Images not showing view properly

Tags: android, android-layout, virtual-reality, google-vr

I am developing a VR App but in VR app Designing and other VRVideoview and Images not showing view properly in which it shows only properly with one eye but not showing with two eyes please give me some solution on that.

I am testing it with Samsung Gear VR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Showing video and image with two eyes with the proper view I have just added following code and its work fine for me in VR mode.

```
 videoWidgetView.setDisplayMode(VrWidgetView.DisplayMode.FULLSCREEN_STEREO);
```